# Finding lines by first value in text file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to extract lines from a large tab delimited text file (18 columns by 20600 rows, 'target file') using a separate 'identifier file' (2 columns by 1050 rows). The identifier file contains identifiers in the second column that I need to match with identifiers in the target file (column 1 in the target file). The goal is to find all 1050 matches in the target file and extract all 18 (identifier+17 values) values for each of the matching 1050 rows (i.e. create a 18x1050 file where the first column in the common identifiers). I am trying to accomplish this in python without much luck. This is what I tried:

```
gene_values=[]
with identifier as genelist:
  for line in genelist:
    parts_genelist=text.split()

  with target as expression:
    for line in expression:
      parts_expression=text.split() 

      if parts_genelist[1]==parts_expression[0]:
           gene_values=gene_values.append[genelist.readlines(), expression.readlines()]
```

I would appreciate some input and some help on doing this better.

Comment: Please post a snippet/sample of both the 'target file' and 'identifier file'

Comment: What goes wrong? Do you have some small example input files to demonstrate the expected and actual output? Also, what is `text` in your code: that variable comes from nowhere (as does `identifier`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That shouldn't be too difficult:

Read all the identifiers into a `set`:

```
idents = set()
with open("identifiers.txt") as ids:
   for line in ids:
       idents.add(line.split()[1])
```

Then iterate through your target file, checking for matching identifiers:

```
matches = []
with open("target.txt") as target:
    for line in target:
        items = line.split()
        if items[0] in idents:
            matches.append(items)
```

(Of course we could do the same thing with two one-liners (set and list comprehension), but I think this code is easier to understand.)

```
with open("identifiers.txt") as ids, open("target.txt") as target:
    idents = {line.split()[1] for line in ids}
    matches = [line.split() for line in target if line.split()[0] in idents]
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. It does partially accomplish what I need to do. One more question: I would like to have the end result to contain one more thing from the identifier file. It is organized as module1 <tab> gene1 in each line. I would like to have the end file contain the module affiliation of each gene is a separate column. Using idents.add(line.split()[0:1]) does not work as I get an 'unhashable list' error. What is the easiest way to amend the script you created to accomplish this?

Comment: So in effect you want to merge the two files, keeping all the information from each line where the identifiers match? That's quite a different question, and it requires a different solution. I think it would be best if you asked another question for this (and @message me when you do).

Comment: Thanks, I did post a new question under [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509787/merge-two-tab-delimited-text-files-by-one-common-column-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You are not clear about what you want. An exemple would be helpfull. As I understand, you want to check each line with a list of patterns. You have many patterns and a large number of lines. The better would be to use regex. Something like that:

```
compiled = re.compile("|".join("($"+pattern+")" for pattern in patterns))
out = [line for line in target_file if compiled.match(line)]
```

You may have to escape yours patterns before, if they have special chars.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `list = list.append()` is not going to do what you want. `list.append()` is a list method that appends the argument to the list and returns `None`, so you're just setting your list equal to `None` every iteration.

As for the rest of the question, an example would be helpful.