# Merge two tab delimited text files by one common column in python

Tags: python, merge

@tim-pietzcker I would like to merge two tab-delimited text files that share one common column. I have an 'identifier file' that looks like this (2 columns by 1050 rows):

> module 1  gene 1
>    module 1  gene 2
>    ..
>    module x  gene y

I also have a tab-delimited 'target' text file that looks like this (36 columns by 12000 rows):

> gene 1  sample 1  sample 2 etc
>   gene 2  sample 1  sample 2 etc
>   ..
>   gene z  sample 1  sample 2 etc

I would like to merge the two files based on the gene identifier and have both the matching expression values and module affiliations from the identifier and target files. Essentially to take the genes from the identifier file, find them in the target file and create a new file with module #, gene # and expression values all in one file. Your suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: So, others are not allowed to answer this question? :-)

Comment: What's your desired output? give a sample?

Comment: @ashwini-chaudhary Of course they are. I just had a question answer session with another user on a related topic.

Comment: @alvas Desired output is gene # <tab> module affiliation <tab> sample values separated by tab.

Comment: @user3107521 Using someone's name in your question body is not going to notify them in any way, @ tags are only work in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Open the gene descripion file, and load a dictionary where key would be the gene number, and the value would be the sample description.

Then open the module file, and loop on its lines. For each line, look for the corresponding gene entry in the dictionary. Print the module, gene, sample description.

That's it! If you need more information, check how to read a file and use a dictionary in the python documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. This is what I came up with. It does not produce any error messages but give me an empty file. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I would appreciate some advice.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I came up with a solution but have an issue. The script written does not produce any error messages but it gives me an empty file. I posted a new question [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540072/merging-two-files-by-one-common-set-of-identifiers-with-python)